# Vim - change status line colours in .vimrc?

Tags: vim, background-color, statusbar

From this question : [How can I change vim status line colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9065941/364088) I learnt how to change the status line colouring, like this :

```
hi StatusLine ctermbg=3 ctermfg=4
```

That's fine but how can I do that for every window, all the time rather than having to apply the command for each new window that I open. I would expect to do this in .vimrc but I can't work out how to .

I'm running vim in a terminal not a gui; I'm using desert as a colorscheme.

---

ANSWER!:
After the answers offered by Ingo and Kent reassured me that I was doing the right thing it still didn't work. Then I discovered I had a line in my vimrc which read

set background = dark

I'm not sure why that was in there but when I commented it out I got the status line colours I wanted.

---

**NOT THE ANSWER !**:
Hmm OK. I've just discovered that making that change to .vimrc does indeed give me the right colours when I was editting vimrc but when I edit python files the status colours are gone. I'm guessing this is something to do with filetypes=on ?

Either way I'll have to re-ask this question when I have more time to think about it but it seems the 'set background = dark' thing was a problem but it's not the entire solution.

For what's worth my vimrc looks like this :

```
colorscheme desert
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py syntax on
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py set ai
autocmd BufRead *.py set smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,with,try,except,finally,def,class
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
filetype indent on
"GLAUCON START
:set ignorecase "make searches case insensitive by default
:set incsearch
:set hlsearch
" Returns true if paste mode is enabled
function! HasPaste()
    if &paste
        return 'PASTE MODE  '
    en
        return ''
endfunction
" Always show the status line
set laststatus=2
" Format the status line
set statusline=\ %{HasPaste()}%F%m%r%h\ %w\ \ CWD:\ %r%{getcwd()}%h\ \ \ Line:\ %l
hi StatusLine ctermbg=3 ctermfg=4
"set background=dark
"GLAUCON END
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to put the `:hi` command **after** any `:colorscheme` command in your `~/.vimrc`, as the colorscheme probably provides its own definition. Similar for `:set background=...` and `:syntax on`.

If the statusline colors still vanish, maybe (this wasn't totally clear from your question) even when switching / opening new windows, there must be an `:autocmd` that does this. Check your installed plugins then.

Comment: Thank you, your comments led me to the right answer. I've edited the question to include what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Errh since then I've discovered it's a bit more subtle than I thought, see second edit to question

Comment: It's that `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.py syntax on`, that's nonsense. Do `:syntax on` globally, then define your `:hi`ghlightings.

Answer (score 3):

I think the `StatusLine` is ok (with big `S`). the problem is (I guess):

you put the `hi StatusLin...` before your `colorscheme desert` call. so that the colorscheme overwrites your statusline highlighting.

You should put it after the `colorscheme desert` in your `.vimrc`

Comment: Thank you, your (and Ingos) comments led me to the right answer. I've edited the question to include what I was doing wrong.

Comment: As above - I've discovered it's a bit more subtle than I thought, see second edit to question