# How to display vim mode in ruler?

Tags: macos, vim, iterm2

I am using Vi IMproved 7.4 in iterm2(version-Build 2.1.4) on MACOS 10.11.4. I wanted to know how to display the current mode of vim operation(insert, normal, visual) in the ruler.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the VI and Vim community within stack exchange

Comment: `:help 'showmode'`

Comment: @romainl : Thank you for the response. I got to know it is called showmode, but how do I enable it in my vim?

Comment: Add `set showmode` to your `vimrc`.

Comment: It did not work for me.

Comment: Right -- it should be on by default, so it may be that something else is up.  Can you troubleshoot:  Open a file, then enter `:set showmode` (hit Enter).  Then go into insert mode ... do you get the notification?  The very last line should show clear `-- INSERT --`.

Answer (score 2):

The `set showmode` should be on by default in `vim`.  If it isn't there may well be something else going on. This should be investigated, but there is also another way which may be very handy.

The color and the highlight patterns of the status line can be changed when you change editing modes. For this you need to have the status line enabled in the first place (`laststatus`). 
Here is an example for lines to enter in your `.vimrc` if you only need to set up `gvim`.

```
set laststatus=2
au InsertEnter * hi StatusLine guibg=Red
au InsertLeave * hi StatusLine guibg=#ccdc90
```

The `au` is short for [`autocmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html). 
For more see `:help InsertEnter` and, for example, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147157/vim-change-the-status-line-color-in-insert-mode).

If you are running `vim` right in a terminal it's a little different.  For example,

```
set laststatus=2
au InsertEnter * hi StatusLine term=reverse ctermbg=Yellow  ctermfg=DarkBlue
au InsertLeave * hi StatusLine term=reverse ctermbg=DarkRed ctermfg=LightGray
```

---

The first part of the above lines, `au InsertEnter * ...`, specifies that the following command is to be executed when `InsertEnter` event happens (for any file, per the pattern `*`).  The second part, `hi StatusLine ...` sets up the `highlight` command for the `statusline`.  (The same is for `InsertLeave` line.)

There are many options for what you can do with highlighting, see [`highlight`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#%3ahighlight) documentation, and many SO posts (for example the one linked above).

For an elaborate yet practical example, which explains a whole lot about `statusline`, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065941/how-can-i-change-vim-status-line-colour). For an extremely detailed presentation of `statusline` examples see [this blog](http://got-ravings.blogspot.com/2008/08/vim-pr0n-making-statuslines-that-own.html).

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @romaini in comments, you can use

> set showmode

You don't see "normal" because by default, vim is in that state. For all other states, you would see messages like

> --insert--,   --replace--,  --visual--